# Can I use a normal function, not a method selector, as an event handler in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm really bad at objective C, and I need to write this one button click handler. Currently I have this:

```
NSButton *button = ...
[button setAction:buttonPressed];
// This also doesn't work
[button setAction:@selector(buttonPressed)];

void buttonPressed() { NSLog(@"Button pressed!"); }
```

As I understand, setAction() requires a selector which is kind of like a method pointer. I don't have any classes here, so no methods. Is there a way to use a simple function for the button click event?

Thanks

Comment: How can you have no class? Where is this code that you posted?

Comment: I have a simple app I write without X Code. Currently there are two functions: main() and buttonPressed(). Looks like I need to define  a class to set an event handler.

Comment: No AppDelegate? No view controller? No nothing? :) Just work through some Objective-C tutorials that has some UI. You will kick your ass what you've been missing the past 20 years or so. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot just pass some (reference to a) plain C function to something that expects an Objective-C method selector. Of course, you can wrap your method up in some class and call your native method from there.

A simplified explanation is that the method will be called "on some object"; that's just how the framework works here.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the quick response. Coming from C and Go, that's really weird :)

Comment: You should perhaps read a little about how methods are invoked. That is not just a function call, it is the result of a message. Apple explains it quite nicely.

Comment: BTW, here's a link to the docs by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html